# UDP socket programming(extracting the data, storing it in a string)

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, network-programming, udp

I am learning about TCP and UDP socket programming with Java, one of the books i am reading for my networking class has the following line:

```
DatagramPacket receivedPacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData, receiveData.length);

String modifiedSentence = new String(receivedPacket.getData());
```

Where receivedPacked is just a DatagramPacket type Object and modifiedSentence stores what was returned from the server. ReceivedPacket.getData() converts the packet from bytes to the string in this case before storing it.

My question is why create an object of a string and storing/passing the converted packet to it rather than using the following:

```
String modifiedSentence = receivedPacket.getData();
```

Would this not work? I thought in Java it was impractical to specifically create an object of the String class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DatagramPacket.getData()` returns a byte array not a string. Thus you need to convert it to a string to assign it to a string.

Comment: Oh i see, i thought for some reason the .getData() method's job also involved converting the bytes to string. Would Doing String modifiedSentence = (String)(receivedPacket.getData()); work? Can i typecast the bytes received to a string type like this? Or does it need to specifically create the object with the "new" keyword.

Comment: No, you can't cast it. You need to use new String()

Answer (score 0):

> String modifiedSentence = new String(receivedPacket.getData())

That's wrong anyway. It should be

```
String modifiedSentence = new String(receivedPacket.getData(), 0, receivedPacket.getLength())
```

> My question is why create an object of a string and storing/passing the converted packet to it rather than using the following:
>
> String modifiedSentence = receivedPacket.getData();

Because it doesn't compile. `getData()` returns `byte[]`, not a `String`.

> I thought in Java it was impractical to specifically create an object of the String class.

Only if the argument already is a `String.` In this case it isn't.